# JQuery doesn't work with Onsen UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, onsen-ui

I am working on an app using PhoneGap and Onsen UI. However, I found out that I am not able to use jQuery for the app. So I have added the following jQuery CDN path. But still it is not working. How can I incorporate the functionality of jQuery together with Onsen UI?

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

<!-- JS dependencies (order matters!) -->
<script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>
<!--<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- CSS dependencies -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsenui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsen-css-components-blue-basic-theme.css" />

<!-- CSP support mode (required for Windows Universal apps) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/angular/angular-csp.css" />
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the direct library instead of the CND path? Sometimes there are some issues about that, with Cordova apps

Comment: Yes, now I have used direct library, however, the jQuery seems to be only work for once. y code is as follows:

`<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("#p1").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("#p1").show();
    });
});
</script>

<p id="p1">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>

<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>`

Comment: It's better to load jQuery before AngularJS. There shouldn't be any problem apart from that. jQuery working here: http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/doMdbw

Answer (score 0):

Per your original posting (using the jQuery CDN), I think you had a couple of things going on:

1. Angular uses its own subset of jquery called "jQLite" when jQuery is not loaded - if your jquery code is not working without loading the library, jQLite must not support it.

   You load in the full jQuery library, but you're using 1.11.3 - try jQuery 2.1 or above, which are the only versions supported.  As per the Angular docs,  *"Angular 1.3 only supports jQuery 2.1 or above. jQuery 1.7 and newer might work correctly with Angular but we don't guarantee that."* https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq
2. Check your config.xml to see if `cordova-plugin-whitelist` is included.  Add `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />` inside the `widget` tags if not.  Access to external files is only permitted if this plugin is enabled (see https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist for details).

    Also be sure to check whether your `config.xml` file includes `access` tags - these tags allow cordova to access files from the specified locations.  If none are specified, only local files are permitted (via `file://`) - so `http://` and `https://` calls, like you have for your CDN for jQuery, won't be allowed.  Cordova should include the `<access origin="*" />` line by default (which would permit access to anything external by default) but if it's not there and you don't have any other `access` lines, that could be why.  Note also this will only work if the Whitelist Plugin (above) is enabled.  Check the plugin's docs for details about how to permit what, and how to ensure you're doing so securely.  I understand though that including files locally will make your app load much more quickly.